# How to Use Guzzle to Send Files to Client's Web Browser?

Tags: php, http, guzzle

So, I have the following code below, intending to have a PDF file download on the client's web browser. However, though I tested file creation via a sink on my local machine, getting to modify said code to actually output a file via the means I now intend to is proving to be rather challenging. Am I missing some pertinent information necessary for this browser-based file transfer to occur? If not, what could be going wrong here?

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->request('POST', 'http://.../api/report', [
    'headers' => [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="report.pdf"'
    ],
    'body' => 
    '{ 
        "template":{"name":"foobar_report"}, 
        "data" : ' . $json .
    '}'
]);
```

Comment: Guzzle is a library that acts as an HTTP client.  It is often used to solve the same types of problems as CURL.  This is obviously just a snippet of code, but I see no place that you are returning data to the client and that certainly doesn't require Guzzle.  PHP inherently returns HTML via HTTP.   The header setting you are doing would be done using the header() function.  I'm not clear if you need Guzzle here, although perhaps you do to retrieve the report data, but you don't use guzzle to return data to the client.

Comment: If you want the client to download the PDF, Guzzle is not what you are looking for. You should send the headers and file contents on its own, without the use of Guzzle.